# The Euler's project

Tags: javascript, html

The question is 
Let d(n) be defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n).
If d(a) = b and d(b) = a, where a ≠ b, then a and b are an amicable pair and each of a and b are called amicable numbers.

For example, the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.

Evaluate the sum of all the amicable numbers under 10000?

And i tried the answer using java script.The html code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" href="15.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">button</button>
       <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
        var total = 10000;
        var halfTotal = total / 2;
        var amicableNumbers = [];
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < halfTotal; i++)
           {
           if (total % i === 0)
             {
             amicableNumbers.push(i);
             sum += i;
             }
           }
   console.log("Sum of all amicable numbers under " + total + " is " + sum);
     console.log(amicableNumbers);
      }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>





And the CSS code is:
    function myFun(){
    console.log("Hello")
  }
```

I am not getting the exact output of the problem.

Comment: Then what you get instead? What is the actual problem you're facing with the code?

Comment: your list of what you think are amicable numbers is just a list of the divisors of 10000 - and your sum is just the sum of the divisors of 10000 - your code is not even close